# Error Checking for PDO Prepared Statements

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create proper error handling for queries on a MySQL database using PDO prepared statements. I want the program to exit the moment an error in the prepared statement process is detected. Taking advantage of the fact that each step in the PDO prepared statement process returns `False` on failure, I threw together this repugnant hack:

```
 $success = $selectQueryResult = $db->prepare($selectQuery);
 checkSuccess($success);
 $success = $selectQueryResult->bindParam(':value', $fieldValue, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 checkSuccess($success);
 $success = $selectQueryResult->execute();
 checkSuccess($success);
```

with `checkSuccess()` doing the following:

```
function checkSuccess($success) {
    if ($success == false) {
        //TODO: custom error page. 
        echo "Error connecting to database with this query.";
        die();
    }
}
```

Two things. First, this is horribly verbose and stupid. There must be a better way. Obviously I could store the booleans in an array or something to take out a line or 2 of code, but still.

Second, is it even necessary to check these values, or should I just check the result after I perform this line of code:

```
$result = $selectQueryResult->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

As much as I try to break the prepared statement process by inserting weird, mismatched, or lengthy queries, my program always makes it to the `$result` assignment without returning `false` on any of the functions where I run `checkSuccess()`. So maybe I don't need to be checking the above logic at all? Keep in mind that I check for a successful database connection earlier in the program.

Comment: [scolding]DONT USE `global`s [/scolding] Check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557787/are-global-variables-in-php-considered-bad-practice-if-so-why

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I prefer setting the error mode to throwing exceptions like this:

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

right after I connect to the database. So every problem will throw an PDOException
So your code would be:

```
$selectQuery = '
                SELECT 
                    *
                FROM 
                    People 
                WHERE 
                    fieldName = :value
';
$selectQueryResult = $db->prepare($selectQuery);
$selectQueryResult->bindParam(':value', $fieldValue);
$selectQueryResult->execute();
```

and PHP will readily provide the error message and even a stack trace that leads to the exact problem spot.

Comment: You should also put the `prepare` statement in the `try` block.

Comment: @YourCommonSense care to share more on that? also.. that is just an example that does a similar thing to what the initial code was trying.. it could as well log to a file, send a message or any type of error handling.. the question was about how to catch errors, not what to do with them

Comment: +1 to @YourCommonSense for reassuring me that if I'm doing a quick and dirty implementation, leaving out the exception handling will likely report the errors without any additional code.

Comment: I disagree on the insecurity of try / catch blocks. It all depends upon how you handle them. Throw them out to the display, sure they are, log them some place.. in a file outside the web root, in a database thats not publicly accessible.. these things are more secure.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Your comment doesn't make any sense

Comment: @Dr.Dan as the author that he downvoted: I do understand what he means, it's not good practice to catch every exception in your app, maybe just the ones you can recover from, but in genral there should be a general handler. 

*BUT* I did not change the answer because it is in line with what was asked for, as it had to be the equivalent of an approach that used `die` in case of error. How to design your app architecture it's another issue, the answer covered what was asked.

Answer (score 6):

The fact is, you don't need a try catch statement to make PHP throw an exception. Instead, configure the `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` [PDO error mode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php).

After that, once a query fails, PHP will do *exactly what you want*: the program exits immediately, providing a helpful error message and a stack trace.

Only use try..catch in case you are going to handle the error somehow (rollback a transaction for example).

[PDOException](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdoexception.php)

Comment: And make sure that PDO throws exceptions: `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Comment: Is this secure for code deployed to the public? Or does it risk displaying sensitive information about my tables?

Comment: @user1427661 You should never display technical error messages on a live site. Just make sure they are logged.

Comment: So then could I still have the error reporting enabled, but just have the try  ... catch block log the error and display a custom error page with a vague statement about database connection failure?

Comment: -1. NEVER use try..catch just to spit out an error. it is useless, redundant and insecure

Comment: @YourCommonSense That's a bit harsh, the code in the `catch` does not actually spit anything out: `//Do your error handling here` sounds about right to me.